# Unity game white screen

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I was using Unity 5.6.f, now I have upgraded to version 2018.2.6.

My game worked perfectly on my Samsung Edge 7, but now when I make a build, all I see is just a full white screen. I tried to change the settings and the camera properties but with no luck.

Note: My game used to start with background music but now I don't hear anything. Also the unity splash screen doesn't show up, there is just a blank white screen!

What should I do? What is wrong with my settings?

Here is my Logcat:

```
09-10 23:52:56.548 3659-3785/? D/SamsungAlarmManager: Expired : 8
09-10 23:52:56.548 3659-3785/? I/SamsungAlarmManager: setLocked to kernel - T:3 / 20180910T235300, SetElapsed=651150845, nowELAPSED=651147393
09-10 23:52:56.549 3659-3785/? V/SamsungAlarmManager: Sending to uid : 11220 action=null alarm=Alarm{4d8e547 type 1 when 1536612776547 com.dianxinos.optimizer.duplay}
09-10 23:52:56.559 3659-10166/? D/SamsungAlarmManager: Cancel Alarm calling from uid:11220 pid :1593 / op:PendingIntent{21f7174: PendingIntentRecord{bd8b994 com.dianxinos.optimizer.duplay startService}}
09-10 23:52:56.571 3659-10166/? D/SamsungAlarmManager: setInexact Intent (T:1/F:0/AC:false) 20180910T235316 - CU:11220/CP:1593
09-10 23:52:56.870 3659-10166/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
09-10 23:52:56.870 3659-10166/? W/android.os.Debug: failed to get memory consumption info: -1
09-10 23:52:57.019 3659-10166/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
09-10 23:52:57.019 3659-10166/? W/android.os.Debug: failed to get memory consumption info: -1
09-10 23:52:57.396 4135-4372/? D/NetworkController.MobileSignalController(0/3): onDataActivity: direction=2
09-10 23:52:58.409 4135-4372/? D/NetworkController.MobileSignalController(0/3): onDataActivity: direction=0
09-10 23:52:59.610 3659-21830/? D/BatteryService: !@BatteryListener : batteryPropertiesChanged!
09-10 23:52:59.611 3659-21830/? D/BatteryService: level:59, scale:100, status:2, health:2, present:true, voltage: 3976, temperature: 359, technology: Li-ion, AC powered:false, USB powered:true, POGO powered:false, Wireless powered:false, icon:17303851, invalid charger:0, maxChargingCurrent:0, maxChargingVoltage:0, chargeCounter:0
    online:6, current avg:794, charge type:1, power sharing:false, high voltage charger:false, capacity:280000, batterySWSelfDischarging:false, misc_event:0, current_event:0, current_now:814
09-10 23:52:59.612 3659-3659/? D/BatteryService: Sending ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED.
09-10 23:52:59.618 3659-3659/? I/MotionRecognitionService: Plugged
09-10 23:52:59.619 3659-3659/? I/MotionRecognitionService: connected - grip disable
09-10 23:52:59.628 4135-4135/? D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor: received broadcast android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED
09-10 23:52:59.629 4135-4135/? D/BatteryController: onReceive-ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED : mLevel=59, mBatteryStatus=2
09-10 23:52:59.640 4135-4135/? D/PowerUI: priorPlugType = 2 mPlugType =  2
09-10 23:52:59.647 3659-4661/? D/ConnectivityService: filterNetworkStateForUid() uid: 11220 networkInfo: [type: MOBILE[LTE] - MOBILE, state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: (unspecified), extra: we, failover: false, available: true, roaming: false, metered: true]
09-10 23:52:59.652 4135-4135/? D/PowerUI.Notification: showChargingNotice oldChargingType : 1 currentChargingType : 1 oldChargingTime : 5516000 mChargingTime : 5501000
09-10 23:52:59.653 4135-4135/? D/PowerUI.Notification: showChargingNotification()
09-10 23:52:59.654 3659-4924/? D/ConnectivityService: filterNetworkStateForUid() uid: 11354 networkInfo: [type: MOBILE[LTE] - MOBILE, state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: (unspecified), extra: we, failover: false, available: true, roaming: false, metered: true]
09-10 23:52:59.658 3659-5590/? D/ConnectivityService: filterNetworkStateForUid() uid: 11220 networkInfo: [type: MOBILE[LTE] - MOBILE, state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: (unspecified), extra: we, failover: false, available: true, roaming: false, metered: true]
09-10 23:52:59.662 3659-4661/? D/ConnectivityService: filterNetworkStateForUid() uid: 11354 networkInfo: [type: MOBILE[LTE] - MOBILE, state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: (unspecified), extra: we, failover: false, available: true, roaming: false, metered: true]
09-10 23:52:59.667 3659-4661/? D/ConnectivityService: filterNetworkStateForUid() uid: 10193 networkInfo: [type: MOBILE[LTE] - MOBILE, state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: (unspecified), extra: we, failover: false, available: true, roaming: false, metered: true]
09-10 23:52:59.671 4135-4135/? D/Notification: allPendingIntents
09-10 23:52:59.673 3659-5667/? D/ConnectivityService: filterNetworkStateForUid() uid: 10193 networkInfo: [type: MOBILE[LTE] - MOBILE, state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: (unspecified), extra: we, failover: false, available: true, roaming: false, metered: true]
09-10 23:52:59.676 3659-4924/? D/API test: getContainerInfo: value is 
    getContainerInfo: value is 
09-10 23:52:59.707 3659-3659/? D/MotionRecognitionService:   mCableConnection= 1
    clear SAR_DEVICE_GRIP (setPowerConnected) 
09-10 23:52:59.708 3659-3659/? D/SamsungPhoneWindowManager: ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED - Level :: 59, battStatus :: 2
09-10 23:52:59.708 3659-3801/? E/MotionRecognitionService: handleMessage: event 200 value : 1
09-10 23:52:59.710 3659-3689/? D/UsbDeviceManager: handleMessage -> MSG_UPDATE_CHARGING_STATE = 1
09-10 23:52:59.711 3659-3659/? D/EdgeLightingManager: isCallingUserSupported : callingUserId=-1, mUserId=0, isDualAppId=false
09-10 23:52:59.714 3659-3659/? D/AudioService: getStreamVolume 5 index 0
09-10 23:52:59.720 3659-4924/? D/Notification: allPendingIntents
09-10 23:52:59.721 3659-10166/? D/Notification: allPendingIntents
09-10 23:52:59.721 3659-5667/? D/Notification: allPendingIntents
09-10 23:52:59.727 5021-5021/? D/CatchNotificationsService: onNotificationPosted
09-10 23:52:59.728 3659-5667/? D/Notification: allPendingIntents
09-10 23:52:59.731 3659-4924/? D/Notification: allPendingIntents
09-10 23:52:59.732 3659-3801/? D/MotionRecognitionService: clear TransmitPower  value : 1
    clear TransmitPower  value : 1
09-10 23:52:59.745 5087-25650/? D/BadgeProvider: query, [selection] : null
09-10 23:52:59.763 5021-5021/? E/CatchNotificationsService: Invalid notification data
09-10 23:52:59.797 4135-4135/? W/StaticLayout: maxLineHeight should not be -1.  maxLines:1 lineCount:1
09-10 23:52:59.800 4135-4135/? I/chatty: uid=10064(u0_a64) com.android.systemui identical 2 lines
09-10 23:52:59.801 4135-4135/? W/StaticLayout: maxLineHeight should not be -1.  maxLines:1 lineCount:1
09-10 23:52:59.805 5050-5070/? I/zygote64: Background concurrent copying GC freed 20115(989KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 66% free, 770KB/2MB, paused 21.115ms total 83.742ms
09-10 23:52:59.828 4135-4135/? W/StaticLayout: maxLineHeight should not be -1.  maxLines:1 lineCount:1
09-10 23:53:00.001 3659-3785/? D/SamsungAlarmManager: Expired : 8
09-10 23:53:00.002 3659-3785/? I/SamsungAlarmManager: setLocked to kernel - T:3 / 20180910T235316, SetElapsed=651167568, nowELAPSED=651150846
09-10 23:53:00.003 3659-3785/? V/SamsungAlarmManager: Sending to uid : 1000 action=android.intent.action.TIME_TICK alarm=Alarm{696712 type 3 when 651150845 android}
09-10 23:53:00.008 3659-3659/? D/SamsungAlarmManager: setExact Intent (T:3/F:1/AC:false) 20180910T235359 - CU:1000/CP:3659
09-10 23:53:00.010 4135-4135/? D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor: received broadcast android.intent.action.TIME_TICK
09-10 23:53:00.011 4135-4135/? D/KeyguardServiceBoxContainer: refreshTime() 1
09-10 23:53:00.594 3286-3286/? E/audit: type=1400 audit(1536612780.591:84424): avc:  denied  { read } for  pid=21505 comm=43707520436F6C6C656374696F6E name="stat" dev="proc" ino=4026534927 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app_25:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:proc_stat:s0 tclass=file permissive=0 SEPF_SM-G935F_8.0.0_0011 audit_filtered
09-10 23:53:00.630 4697-4697/? D/io_stats: !@   8,0 r 13057802 526259596 w 3460694 64451520 d 486779 24649384 f 938215 937809 iot 10758130 9080915 th 375916 0 0 pt 0 inp 0 0 210836.246
09-10 23:53:01.435 4135-4372/? D/NetworkController.MobileSignalController(0/3): onDataActivity: direction=2
09-10 23:53:01.626 9154-9154/? D/Notification: allPendingIntents
09-10 23:53:01.641 9154-9154/? D/Notification: allPendingIntents
09-10 23:53:01.649 3659-3680/? D/API test: getContainerInfo: value is 
09-10 23:53:01.655 3659-3659/? D/EdgeLightingManager: isCallingUserSupported : callingUserId=0, mUserId=0, isDualAppId=false
09-10 23:53:01.656 3659-3659/? D/EdgeLightingManager: showForNotification : isInteractive=true, isHeadUp=false, color=0, sbn = StatusBarNotification(pkg=com.dianxinos.optimizer.duplay user=UserHandle{0} id=439 tag=null key=0|com.dianxinos.optimizer.duplay|439|null|11220: Notification(channel=null pri=2 contentView=com.dianxinos.optimizer.duplay/0x7f040196 vibrate=null sound=null defaults=0x0 flags=0x62 color=0x00000000 number=0 vis=PRIVATE semFlags=0x0 semPriority=0 semMissedCount=0))
09-10 23:53:01.656 3659-3659/? D/EdgeLightingClientManager: isAvailableEdgeLighting: condition=1 mCondition=3 mIsConnected=false1
09-10 23:53:01.657 3659-3659/? D/EdgeLightingPolicyManager: isAcceptableApplication:  pkg=com.dianxinos.optimizer.duplay , range=256 , includeAllApp=false , userId=0 , infoRange=0 , infoCategory=0
    putNotification tickerText:false,titleText:false,text:false,sub:falsecn= + null
09-10 23:53:01.658 3659-3659/? D/EdgeLightingPolicyManager.NotificationGroup: updateNotificationData put :0|com.dianxinos.optimizer.duplay|439|null|11220,size=3
    0|com.dianxinos.dxbs|2|null|10193:NotificationData time=1536612769757,
    0|com.dianxinos.optimizer.duplay|439|null|11220:NotificationData time=1536612781657,
    0|com.duapps.antivirus|1024|DuScene|11354:NotificationData time=1536610136399,
09-10 23:53:01.658 3659-3659/? D/EdgeLightingManager: showForNotificationScreenOn : texts are empty.
09-10 23:53:01.673 3659-4924/? D/Notification: allPendingIntents
09-10 23:53:01.675 3659-10166/? D/Notification: allPendingIntents
09-10 23:53:01.677 3659-3659/? D/Notification: allPendingIntents
09-10 23:53:01.678 3659-4661/? D/Notification: allPendingIntents
09-10 23:53:01.681 5021-5021/? D/CatchNotificationsService: onNotificationPosted
09-10 23:53:01.685 3659-10166/? D/Notification: allPendingIntents
09-10 23:53:01.689 3659-5590/? D/Notification: allPendingIntents
09-10 23:53:01.698 5087-25650/? D/BadgeProvider: query, [selection] : null
09-10 23:53:01.708 5021-5021/? E/CatchNotificationsService: Invalid notification data
09-10 23:53:01.762 4135-4135/? D/swipe: !isFreemformEnabled
09-10 23:53:02.448 4135-4372/? D/NetworkController.MobileSignalController(0/3): onDataActivity: direction=0
09-10 23:53:03.459 4135-4372/? D/NetworkController.MobileSignalController(0/3): onDataActivity: direction=3
09-10 23:53:04.347 17576-17633/? I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
09-10 23:53:04.348 17576-17633/? I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
09-10 23:53:05.479 4135-4372/? D/NetworkController.MobileSignalController(0/3): onDataActivity: direction=2
09-10 23:53:05.600 3286-3286/? E/audit: type=1400 audit(1536612785.591:84425): avc:  denied  { read } for  pid=21505 comm=43707520436F6C6C656374696F6E name="stat" dev="proc" ino=4026534927 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app_25:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:proc_stat:s0 tclass=file permissive=0 SEPF_SM-G935F_8.0.0_0011 audit_filtered
09-10 23:53:05.635 4697-4697/? D/io_stats: !@   8,0 r 13057802 526259596 w 3460709 64451608 d 486779 24649384 f 938219 937813 iot 10758140 9080919 th 375856 0 0 pt 0 inp 0 0 210841.252
09-10 23:53:06.507 3659-9981/? D/SSRM:O: SIOP:: AP = 390, PST = 388 (W:14), BAT = 359, CHG = 395, CP = 347
09-10 23:53:07.499 4135-4372/? D/NetworkController.MobileSignalController(0/3): onDataActivity: direction=3
09-10 23:53:09.518 4135-4372/? D/NetworkController.MobileSignalController(0/3): onDataActivity: direction=0
09-10 23:53:09.659 3659-5590/? D/ConnectivityService: filterNetworkStateForUid() uid: 10201 networkInfo: [type: MOBILE[LTE] - MOBILE, state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: (unspecified), extra: we, failover: false, available: true, roaming: false, metered: true]
09-10 23:53:09.671 3659-21830/? D/BatteryService: !@BatteryListener : batteryPropertiesChanged!
09-10 23:53:09.672 3659-21830/? D/BatteryService: level:59, scale:100, status:2, health:2, present:true, voltage: 3975, temperature: 359, technology: Li-ion, AC powered:false, USB powered:true, POGO powered:false, Wireless powered:false, icon:17303851, invalid charger:0, maxChargingCurrent:0, maxChargingVoltage:0, chargeCounter:0
    online:6, current avg:796, charge type:1, power sharing:false, high voltage charger:false, capacity:280000, batterySWSelfDischarging:false, misc_event:0, current_event:0, current_now:798
09-10 23:53:09.673 3659-3659/? D/BatteryService: Sending ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED.
09-10 23:53:09.679 3659-3659/? I/MotionRecognitionService: Plugged
    connected - grip disable
09-10 23:53:09.686 4135-4135/? D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor: received broadcast android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED
09-10 23:53:09.694 4135-4135/? D/BatteryController: onReceive-ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED : mLevel=59, mBatteryStatus=2
09-10 23:53:09.704 4135-4135/? D/PowerUI: priorPlugType = 2 mPlugType =  2
09-10 23:53:09.707 4135-4135/? D/PowerUI.Notification: showChargingNotice oldChargingType : 1 currentChargingType : 1 oldChargingTime : 5501000 mChargingTime : 5501000
    There is no change about charging status, so return!
09-10 23:53:09.715 3659-21830/? D/ConnectivityService: filterNetworkStateForUid() uid: 11220 networkInfo: [type: MOBILE[LTE] - MOBILE, state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: (unspecified), extra: we, failover: false, available: true, roaming: false, metered: true]
09-10 23:53:09.721 3659-21830/? D/ConnectivityService: filterNetworkStateForUid() uid: 11220 networkInfo: [type: MOBILE[LTE] - MOBILE, state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: (unspecified), extra: we, failover: false, available: true, roaming: false, metered: true]
09-10 23:53:09.725 3659-21830/? D/ConnectivityService: filterNetworkStateForUid() uid: 11354 networkInfo: [type: MOBILE[LTE] - MOBILE, state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: (unspecified), extra: we, failover: false, available: true, roaming: false, metered: true]
09-10 23:53:09.743 3659-21830/? D/ConnectivityService: filterNetworkStateForUid() uid: 10193 networkInfo: [type: MOBILE[LTE] - MOBILE, state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: (unspecified), extra: we, failover: false, available: true, roaming: false, metered: true]
09-10 23:53:09.753 3659-5590/? D/ConnectivityService: filterNetworkStateForUid() uid: 10193 networkInfo: [type: MOBILE[LTE] - MOBILE, state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: (unspecified), extra: we, failover: false, available: true, roaming: false, metered: true]
09-10 23:53:09.758 3659-5590/? D/ConnectivityService: filterNetworkStateForUid() uid: 11354 networkInfo: [type: MOBILE[LTE] - MOBILE, state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: (unspecified), extra: we, failover: false, available: true, roaming: false, metered: true]
09-10 23:53:09.789 3659-3659/? D/MotionRecognitionService:   mCableConnection= 1
    clear SAR_DEVICE_GRIP (setPowerConnected) 
09-10 23:53:09.790 3659-3801/? E/MotionRecognitionService: handleMessage: event 200 value : 1
09-10 23:53:09.790 3659-3659/? D/SamsungPhoneWindowManager: ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED - Level :: 59, battStatus :: 2
09-10 23:53:09.791 3659-3689/? D/UsbDeviceManager: handleMessage -> MSG_UPDATE_CHARGING_STATE = 1
09-10 23:53:09.796 3659-3801/? D/MotionRecognitionService: clear TransmitPower  value : 1
    clear TransmitPower  value : 1
09-10 23:53:10.607 3286-3286/? E/audit: type=1400 audit(1536612790.601:84426): avc:  denied  { read } for  pid=21505 comm=43707520436F6C6C656374696F6E name="stat" dev="proc" ino=4026534927 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app_25:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:proc_stat:s0 tclass=file permissive=0 SEPF_SM-G935F_8.0.0_0011 audit_filtered
09-10 23:53:10.641 4697-4697/? D/io_stats: !@   8,0 r 13057802 526259596 w 3460710 64451620 d 486779 24649384 f 938220 937814 iot 10758140 9080920 th 373288 0 0 pt 0 inp 0 0 210846.257
09-10 23:53:11.537 4135-4372/? D/NetworkController.MobileSignalController(0/3): onDataActivity: direction=2
09-10 23:53:11.690 3659-21830/? D/SamsungAlarmManager: Cancel Alarm calling from uid:10020 pid :4782 / op:PendingIntent{df2e25e: PendingIntentRecord{46a9627 com.google.android.gms broadcastIntent}}
09-10 23:53:11.709 3659-21830/? D/SamsungAlarmManager: setExact Intent (T:2/F:5/AC:false) 20180911T000711 - CU:10020/CP:4782
09-10 23:53:11.746 5187-5187/? I/GCM: Message from 745476177629
09-10 23:53:11.804 3659-3679/? D/ConnectivityService: filterNetworkStateForUid() uid: 1000 networkInfo: [type: MOBILE[LTE] - MOBILE, state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: (unspecified), extra: we, failover: false, available: true, roaming: false, metered: true]
09-10 23:53:11.813 3659-3679/? D/ConnectivityService: filterNetworkStateForUid() uid: 10113 networkInfo: [type: MOBILE[LTE] - MOBILE, state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: (unspecified), extra: we, failover: false, available: true, roaming: false, metered: true]
09-10 23:53:11.827 3659-3679/? D/ConnectivityService: filterNetworkStateForUid() uid: 1000 networkInfo: [type: MOBILE[LTE] - MOBILE, state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: (unspecified), extra: we, failover: false, available: true, roaming: false, metered: true]
09-10 23:53:11.863 3659-3679/? D/StorageManagerService: getExternalStorageMountMode : 3
    getExternalStorageMountMode : 3
09-10 23:53:11.864 3659-3679/? D/StorageManagerService: getExternalStorageMountMode : final mountMode=3, uid : 10113, packageName : com.google.android.gm
09-10 23:53:11.864 3659-3679/? D/ActivityManager: package  com.google.android.gm, user - 0 is SDcard whitelisted
09-10 23:53:11.887 3659-3679/? I/ActivityManager: Start proc 8294:com.google.android.gm/u0a113 for service com.google.android.gm/.provider.MailSyncAdapterService
09-10 23:53:11.887 8294-8294/? E/Zygote: isWhitelistProcess - Process is Whitelisted
09-10 23:53:11.887 3659-3679/? I/ActivityManager: Start proc 8294:com.google.android.gm/u0a113 for service com.google.android.gm/.provider.MailSyncAdapterService
09-10 23:53:11.889 8294-8294/? E/libpersona: scanKnoxPersonas
    Couldn't open the File - /data/system/users/0/personalist.xml - No such file or directory
09-10 23:53:11.894 8294-8294/? W/SELinux: SELinux selinux_android_compute_policy_index : Policy Index[2],  Con:u:r:zygote:s0 RAM:SEPF_SM-G935F_8.0.0_0011, [-1 -1 -1 -1 0 1]
09-10 23:53:11.896 8294-8294/? I/SELinux: SELinux: seapp_context_lookup: seinfo=untrusted, level=s0:c512,c768, pkgname=com.google.android.gm 
09-10 23:53:11.902 8294-8294/? I/zygote64: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
09-10 23:53:11.939 8294-8294/? D/TimaKeyStoreProvider: TimaKeyStore is not enabled: cannot add TimaSignature Service and generateKeyPair Service
09-10 23:53:11.940 8294-8294/? D/ActivityThread: Added TimaKeyStore provider
09-10 23:53:11.946 3659-5590/? I/ActivityManager: DSS on for com.google.android.gm and scale is 1.0
09-10 23:53:12.014 8294-8294/? I/zygote64: no shared libraies, dex_files: 1
09-10 23:53:12.192 8294-8294/? W/ComponentDiscovery: Application info not found.
    Could not retrieve metadata, returning empty list of registrars.
09-10 23:53:12.320 8294-8294/? D/ActivityThread: Loading provider com.google.android.gm.sapi: com.google.android.gm.sapi.SapiUiProvider
09-10 23:53:12.441 3659-5590/? W/StorageManager: getStorageLowBytes lowPercent : 5, lowBytes : 1327564390, maxLowBytes : 524288000
09-10 23:53:12.453 8294-8294/? W/GAV2: Thread[main,5,main]: Need to call initialize() and be in fallback mode to start dispatch.
09-10 23:53:12.495 8294-8324/? I/PrimesTesting: GserviceFlagsSupplier.get()
09-10 23:53:12.544 4135-4372/? D/NetworkController.MobileSignalController(0/3): onDataActivity: direction=3
09-10 23:53:12.607 3659-3679/? D/ConnectivityService: filterNetworkStateForUid() uid: 1000 networkInfo: [type: MOBILE[LTE] - MOBILE, state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: (unspecified), extra: we, failover: false, available: true, roaming: false, metered: true]
09-10 23:53:12.696 3659-4661/? D/ConnectivityService: filterNetworkStateForUid() uid: 10020 networkInfo: [type: MOBILE[LTE] - MOBILE, state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: (unspecified), extra: we, failover: false, available: true, roaming: false, metered: true]
09-10 23:53:12.781 3659-21830/? W/StorageManager: getStorageLowBytes lowPercent : 5, lowBytes : 1327564390, maxLowBytes : 524288000
```

Here is my Menifest file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:installLocation="preferExternal" package="com.example.admobtest" android:versionName="1.0" android:versionCode="1">
  <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true" />
  <!-- Google Mobile Ads Permissions -->
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <application android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="false">


    <!-- meta-data tag for Google Play services -->
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
    <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerProxyActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" >
      <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" android:value="true" />
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" >
      <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" android:value="true" />
      <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name" android:value="unity" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.VideoPlayer" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" >
    </activity>   
    <!-- Google Mobile Ads Activity -->
    <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen">
    </activity>
    <!--Added by ME on 01.09.14 23:17-->
    <activity android:name="com.prime31.GoogleIABProxyActivity"></activity>    
  </application>
  <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" />
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="27" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: Do you get the same results when building for PC or another platform?

Comment: No, only for my Android device

Comment: Have you tried updating your Android SDK?

Comment: Yes. I have no problem making a build on Android Studio for API 27 or 28.

Comment: Yes, I know how to work with Unity3d. The scenes are included and enabled in the build manager.

Comment: @TalAngel I'm not sure, but do you check OpenGL settings? `Edit -> Project Settings -> Player -> Other Settings` in `Rendering` unchecked `Auto Graphics API` and set `Graphic APIs` to `OpenGLES2`

Comment: : ( No, that didn't do the trick. I am stuck on this for days...

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in ADB logcat?

Comment: NO...don't see any errors

Comment: What I told you is what I have. No splash screen pops up, just a blank white screen. No audio also. 
I just upgraded my unity version and now the android build is messed up.

Comment: The fact that even the Unity logo doesn't show is a pretty bad sign. Perhaps you should confirm the following: Remove all scenes from the build manager, add a new blank one, build it and see if it runs. If not something is wrong with your first scene. Secondly, create a new project with Unity 2018.2.6 and build that. Does it work? If so, I'd hazard that there's an issue with your Manifest, although there should be an error in your ADB log.

Comment: OK...I made a simple game with just a blue screen and it's running on my Android device. Now, How do I match the 2 Manifest files and find the big problem here?

Comment: Stick the manifest up so we can take a look at it. While you wait for a reply, perhaps you could delete your current manifest so that Unity creates a new one and see if that helps.

Comment: Have you also updated the unity Remote on your device?

Comment: @StevenCoull I love you! All I had to do was to delete the old Menifest file and now everything works. Post your answer and get +50 reputation from me.

Comment: Glad to help mate!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the issue was caused by a corrupt Android manifest.

For anyone else with this issue, things you should check:

- Can you build and run a new Unity project with your updated Unity version? If not, you may need to update your Android SDK.
- Does your project work on other platforms such as iOS? If it doesn't, you may have an issue in your first scene. Check your logs, and also try replacing it with an empty scene to see if that works.
- If you can build a new project and it works on other platforms, delete your Android Manifest. Unity will create a new one at build time. You may need to re-add additional Activities and Dependancies as your project requires.